# Returning rows from queries executed in loop in pgsql

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to write a query where there is one public schema in which there is environment table containing names of schemas in the same db. I am iterating over the list of schemas returned by the query and one by one trying to find the number of record count for one table which is same in all the schemas. Here I am able to print the result on the console using RAISE NOTICE but I want this to return a row having schema as one column and count as another. I tried RETURN QUERY and INTO too but not able to find a way of getting this. At last I am running this query using python where I am using psycopg2 cur.fetchone().

I tried :

```
DO
$do$
    DECLARE 
    _tbl text;
    c record;
    schema_name VARCHAR:= 'public';
    BEGIN
        FOR _tbl IN 
            SELECT display_name
            FROM public.environment
        LOOP
            EXECUTE 
                format('SELECT count(*) from %I.%I where is_deleted = false' ,_tbl, 'adaptor' )
                INTO c;
                RAISE NOTICE '% -> %', _tbl, to_json(c);
        END LOOP;
    END
$do$
```

Can we get the result of `format('SELECT count(*) from %I.%I where is_deleted = false' ,_tbl, 'test_table' )` as a row?

Answer (score 1):

A `DO` block can not return a result. You need to create a set-returning function for that.

```
create or replace function get_row_counts()
  returns table(schema_name text, table_name text, row_count bigint)
as
$$
DECLARE 
  _tbl text;
 _schema text := 'public';
BEGIN
  FOR _tbl IN 
    SELECT display_name
    FROM public.environment
  LOOP
    return query 
      EXECUTE format('SELECT %L, %L, count(*) from %I.%I where is_deleted = false', 
                     _schema, _tbl, _schema, _tbl);
  END LOOP;
END
$$
language plpgsql;
```

This can be used in a SELECT statement:

```
select * 
from get_row_counts();
```